# Trouble understanding datasets in the Tensorflow RNN Tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Ok, I admit it - this is a bad question.  You should probably downvote it ;) However, as I really NEED some insight, if you could kindly wait until some kind soul answers it first....

I have the RNN tutorial installed and running successfully.  I am a NOOB to this - though I have a decent feel for the code.  Unfortunately, [the TensorFlow RNN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/recurrent/) doesn't define (at least to me) a few critical items needed to understand:

1. What is the logical difference between the training and validation sets?  Specifically, in terms of the file contents in 'ptb.train.txt' and 'ptb.valid.txt'

   For instance, ptb.train.txt contains:

   ```
   there is no asbestos in our products now
   ```

   However, neither `asbestos` nor `in our products` appears in the `ptb.valid.txt`, thus it is unclear what is being trained and what is being validated.
2. My 'Test Perplexity' is reported as 121.236.  What does this mean?  Again, I would really like to know in terms of the 'ptb.test.txt' file - what is that being measured against?

   Another typical example: `ptb.test.txt` contains:

   ```
   the offers were to work as a writer not an editor
   ```

   Neither this 'sequence' nor a close subset appears in either the `ptb.train.txt` or the `ptb.valid.txt` files.  Maybe I am completely off-base, but I thought the intent was to match such sequences.  Is this incorrect?  How does the reported perplexity relate to that?
3. Finally (again, NOOB here), it takes quite a while to train even this simple example.  Is there a way to save the 'trained' system so that I can run it against different test datasets?

   **Update**
   I believe question #3 is [answered in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786771/how-to-use-tensorflows-ptb-model-example)

Answer (score 0):

1. There are a few elements that you need to learn to understand the procedure. Machine Learning algorithms are being trained on a given dataset. These algorithms could potentially “memorize” your whole dataset so they will give you the right answer for your dataset all the time. The *right answer* is the expected result of your problem. If the model memorizes all your train data it will not respond very well to new input data that has not seen, and so his predictive power would not be very good. To train a model to have a better predictive power, you split the dataset in *train* and *validation*, where the validation subset is not used for training but is used to control that the model is not memorizing the *train* dataset.
2. The perplexity is a specific metric to assess how good is the model
3. Yes you can Consult the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables

Comment: I tried to supplement the question with more specifics about what I don't understand.  From your answer, I see my question really missed the mark.  I don't 'see' how the sequences are being validated or tested given the contents of the files nor how perplexity relates to that.

Answer (score 0):

- Training sets are to **optimize** the model.
- Validation datasets are to check if the model is **under fitting** or **over-fitting** the training data.
- After you've trained the model and feel like it is preforming well you use the **test dataset** to check if *you* tuned the model too finely based on the results from your validation datasets and caused your model to over-fit real world data.

Also, these questions belong in https://stats.stackexchange.com/ :)