# Tensorflow: how to use RNN from tutorial (PTB model)

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

There is an example of training RNN on the Tensorflow tutorials page. 
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent

But there are no any examples, how to use trained model?

I found a similar question here [How to use Tensorflow's PTB model example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786771/how-to-use-tensorflows-ptb-model-example) but it looks like not working with the current stable Tensorflow 1.7

Comment: What's the problem you are facing exactly? How is not working? What have your tried so far?

Comment: Unpacking issue, raw_data contains 3 items instead of 5:

train_data, valid_data, test_data, vocabulary, word_to_id, id_to_word = raw_data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve